# Find which web sites have a link to a specific web site?

Tags: google-search, links

Is there any way to find which web sites have a link to a specific web site, using Google search?

Comment: Better for Webmasters, but the question is too broad and would be closed

Comment: @Eight I don't see why it's too-broad or "better for Webmasters": looks like a simple question about Google  search (with which it was tagged).

Comment: @404 I'm fine with reopening if there's a particular syntax/option that can be used.  I think my original contention was with the ambiguity of "put a link" and the OP never clarified.